# Why do am I getting error "java.lang.IllegalStateException" after putting <form:form> tag in jsp file of spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have 2 tables, city and hotel_details in my database. I am trying to fetch the data from these tables and populating inside a form for registering the customer. But I am getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute" as error.

1. JSP file

   ```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Search Hotels</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Search Hotels</h4>
            <form:form action="search">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>City:</td>
                        <td>
                            <form:select path="cities">
                                <form:options items="${cities}" />
                            </form:select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Hotel:</td>
                        <td>
                            <form:select path="hotels">
                                <form:options items="${hotels}" />
                            </form:select>
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td>Date:</td>
                         <td>
                             <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td colspan="3">
                             <input type="submit" value="Check Availability">
                         </td>
                     </tr>
            </table>
    </form:form>
   ```

2. Controller

@Controller
public class HomeController {

```
//need a controller method to show the initial HTML form
@Autowired(required=true)
private CityDAO cityDAO;

@Autowired(required=true)
private HotelDetailsDAO hotelDetailsDAO;

  @RequestMapping("/")  
  public String showCheckAvailablityForm(Model theModel) { 
    // get customers from the dao
      
        //List<City> theCities = cityDAO.getCities();
        List<String> theCities = cityDAO.getCities();
            
        Set<String> theHotels = hotelDetailsDAO.getHotels();
        
        // add the customers to the model
        theModel.addAttribute("cities", theCities);
        
        theModel.addAttribute("hotels", theHotels);
         
        //printing the data fetched
        System.out.println("In HomeController showCheckAvailability method where city name is being fetched from city table");
        theCities.forEach((n) -> System.out.println(n));
        
        System.out.println("printing hotels");
        for (String temp : theHotels) {
            System.out.print(temp + " ");
        }
                
      return "checkAvailability-form"; 
  }
  
    
      @RequestMapping("/search")
      public String searchResult(@RequestParam("cityName") String theCityName, @RequestParam("hotelName") String theHotelName,Model model) {
          System.out.println("processed successfully");
          return null; 
      }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `<form:form>` attribute, it requires you to specify model object that should be bound to `form` tag. If you don't specify any model attribute default name is used as `command`.

Following is the description of `form:form` tag from spring-form.tld -

```
        <attribute>
            <description>Name of the model attribute under which the form object is exposed.
                Defaults to 'command'.</description>
            <name>modelAttribute</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <description>Name of the model attribute under which the form object is exposed.
                Defaults to 'command'.</description>
            <name>commandName</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
```

As you don't have any model object bound to `form`, try removing `form:form` tag and use HTML `form` tag and also make sure you match input parameter names with method parameter names. i.e -

```
         <form action="search">
...
         </form>
```